# How to activate word wrapping in the Console of PyCharm's Debug-Tool-Window as default setting?

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, pycharm, word-wrap

I activated word wrapping as default setting for the Python Console window via: File→Settings→Editor→General→Console: Use soft wraps in console

[image]

This works just fine for the Python Console window, but does not activate the word wrapping for the `Console` tab of the Debug toolwindow.

[image]

Any ideas how set word wrapping as default for the Console of the Debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You can activate it using button to your left, it will stay activated whenever you click 'debug' button:

[image]

Comment: True, but I'd have to redo this every time I open a new PyCharm instance. I'd like this option to be already activated when I open the Debugger for the first time in a PyCharm instance.

Comment: I think there is no option for that... It's only one click when you start pycharm. It will always stay like that when you close debugger.